# Apply function to a filtered group after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-groupby

I know there are tons of groupby-filter questions about pandas, but I've gone through a number of them and they don't have what I need.

Anyway here's what I have for the dataframe `df`:

```
user1   user2  date         quantity
-----------------------------
Alice   Bob    2018-05-21   100
Alice   Bob    2018-05-19   20
Alice   Carol  2018-01-01   1000
Bob     Carol  2018-02-01   100
```

I want to calculate a function (let's say some function `func`) of the quantity for a given `user1-user2` pair for **weekdays** only.

So far what I have are:

```
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.weekday
df.groupby(['user1','user2']).filter(lambda x: (x.day < 5).any() )
```

But I don't get what I expect. Apparently, what the filter does is to select only those pairs where at least one `day` entry is < 5. What I need though, are all rows where the `day` column is less than 5 for one particular `user1-user2` pair.

Comment: Filter first and then groupby?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko I have to do several calculations like this -- this is just  a demo case. So I want to, say, get the sum over weekdays, over weekends, over weeknights, and so on, but always for the same `user1-user2` pair. It's also a pretty large dataset (>10GB) with several rows and >1M `user1-user2` pairs, so if I do that, I'd be doing several groupbys over and over...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward solution is to filter your dataframe *before* you perform the `groupby`:

```
res = df[df['date'].dt.weekday < 5].groupby(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works (same as Yakym's comment earlier), but my only concern is that I'm working with a large dataset and several such operations. How computationally intensive is it to groupby several times (I have around ~1M user1-user2 pairs)? Or is this repeated groupbys not a big deal?

Comment: If you want to change the scope of your `groupby`, I don't see an easy way of avoiding `groupby` several times. I would test performance and *if there is an issue* ask a new question with benchmarking to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!